# How set message in combined JSR-303 annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

Have a look an example:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]*")
@Size(max =5)
@Documented
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {}) //do not want any programmatic validation
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    }
}
```

Example of annotated field:

```
@CustomAnnotation(message = "some important message")
private String field;
```

When field violates @Pattern I get error message from @Pattern not from @CustomAnnotation. It is the way to show only @CustomAnnotation message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the meta-annotation `@ReportAsSingleViolation` to the definition of `CustomConstraint`. That way any violation of one of its composing constraints will be reported as single violation of the composed constraint. See also section [Constraint Composition](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition) in the BV reference.